# satisfiesRule Validation in Aurelia

Tags: validation, aurelia

I want to have a validation rule in Aurelia. I have a boolean array(WeekDays) and when two items of 7 items in this array are true and isAutomatic checkbox is clicked too, it is valid and I can save the data. For example my validation rules:

```
private static VALIDATION_RULES = ValidationRules
.ensure((tc: client.TestConfig) => tc.activateOnWeekDay)
.satisfiesRule('minTwoDaySelected').when((tc: client.TestConfig) => tc.isAutomatic)
.rules
```

I want to write minTwoDaySelected function, which returns true if minimume two items of array are selected. 
The pattern to write it, is here:

```
    ValidationRules.customRule(
      'minTwoDaySelected',
       .....
       .....
    )
```

I don't know how to complete it. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I soled it:

```
ValidationRules.customRule(
  'minTwoDaysSelected',
  (obj) => {
    let i: number
    let count: number = 0
    for ( i = 0;i < 7;i++) {
      if (obj[i]) {
        count++
      }
    }

    return count > 1
  },
  'Minimum two days of \${$displayName} must be selected.',
  (obj) => ({ obj })
)

private static VALIDATION_RULES = ValidationRules
  .ensure((tgc: client.TestGroupTestConfig) => tgc.activateOnWeekDay).displayName('tests.details.week-days')
    .required().satisfiesRule('minTwoDaysSelected').when((tgc: client.TestGroupTestConfig) => tgc.isAutomatic)
  .rules
```

And in html file(View):

```
<input type="hidden" value.bind="batteryConfig.activateOnWeekDay & validate">
```